# Cake: habtm relationship with not-default key on other model

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 2 models that need to be linked by a habtm relationship, having this table-structure:

CATEGORIES:

```
id   |   name   | ..
-----------------------
 1   |   test   | ..
```

POSTS:

```
id   |   name   | other_id | ..
---------------------------------
 1   |   test   | 5        | ..
```

CATEGORIES_POSTS:

```
id   |   category_id | other_id
--------------------------------
 1   |   1           |  5
```

I need to get the posts from the category side, but don't seem to be able to set the habtm relation correctly. The important thing, that I didn't mention so far, is that the id used in the Post-model is **not** `id` but `other_id`. This is what I tried so far (all in the Category-model):

- set the associationForeignKey to 'other_id'

  in the sql-query it has: `CategoriesPost.other_id = Post.id` fragment -> wrong relation (should be `CategoriesPost.other_id = Post.other_id`
- set the associationForeignKey to false and add a condition `CategoriesPost.other_id = Post.other_id`

  now the sql fragment is `CategoriesPost. = Post.id` --> sql error
- set the associationForeignKey to `CategoriesPost.other_id = Post.other_id`

  well .. this is an error as well, as Cake takes the input as 1 field: `CategoriesPost.other_id = Post.other_id = Post.id`

I know I could achieve to relation through 2 hasMany links, but that gives me a lot of queries instead of 1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is _CATEGORIES_POST_ the name of the table? Cake would try to use _CATEGORIES_POSTS_. Otherwise, what's the error message with associationForeignKey = 'other_id'?

Comment: you are right with the join table name. I corrected it above and added the results of my attempts..

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why didn't you follow Cake conventions? That is to say, what's the difference between linking `Post.id` vs `Post.other_id`? Seems to me if they are 1-1, you could save yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: Also, which Model are you attempting to perform the `find()`? Post? or Category? For clarity on attempt #2, did you use array notation or a string for `condition`?

Comment: for the first question: the db-structure I have the problem with has a different structure. Difficult to explain. Each post generates several 'publications' that differ a bit (for example language). So the *real* model is publications. The contents from that model are created by an export of all possible versions of posts -> I have a publication_id and a post_id .. as I said: difficult to explain ---
 
2nd question: err .. I think string, but not very sure to be honest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the post model primaryKey on the fly for some operations you need to....
To do so, just need to do $this->primaryKey = 'other_id' OR in a controller $this->Post->primaryKey= 'other_id'

that would do the trick.

But remember, if you are retrieving data from all associations and you have more associations than this one then the other associations if they use Post.id are going to fail since primary key is Post.other_id

you should do a find function in your post models for when you are using this union, something like this:

```
function otherFind ($type, $options){
    $this->primaryKey = 'other_id';
    $result = $this->find($type, $options);
    $this->primaryKey = 'id';
    return $result;
}
```

if you need to join it with other models gets a little more tricky i will recommend to use joins for that (try looking at the linkable bhaviour code to see how)

I strongly suggest to use only ONE primary key since it's not really helpfull a second one. A primary key should be unique anyway and you can associate anything with just one.

Comment: so easy and yet so clever .. You are right with everything you write (as are Jason and Ivo). To explain the problem a little better than above why I needed this db-design: I build a CMS where content is created in a modular way and where each section depends on 4 vars. It would take too long to create the publications on the fly so I export them to another db and denormalize it. So from the prior main model (docs) are created several publications that are all children of docs (if it would be normalized). However, the categories still link to the docs.. Thanks a lot for (all of your) answer(s)!

Comment: the comment length is too short  :) I reread the above and think again it's difficult to understand .. might be that I need to improve my English 'skills' a bit too

Answer (score 1):

Cake can't customise the primary key to use on the join when doing a normal find.

You could use a custom join, if you really want: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables

Why exactly do you need two ids? You are trying to join a post to a category, the ids will be unique anyway; as far as relating the two, the primary should work just fine.